# Best Practices : Having your PhD Supervisor as your co-author?

Tags: phd, advisor, authorship, supervision, author-order

I am in the process of writing a paper. I have done the data collection, and am in the process of analysis. But somehow my supervisor does not show much interest in my work or my research topic (i am in 2nd year, this is my first paper ), we meet once a month to review my overall progress.

I have a paper submission deadline approaching, Should I mention my supervisor as a co-author?

How should I ask my supervisor, if I can add their name as a co-author?

The thing is that I don't mind either way, adding them or not adding them,

I am just too awkward to start this conversation with them.

Answer (score 3):

**Please** have this conversation with your advisor rather than with us strangers on the Internet. Independently of what you choose, there is a chance that guessing wrong may have severely negative consequences for your future relationship with your advisor. Adding somebody as an author without their knowledge is a big no-no, but on the other hand you can scan our archives to see what fallout may happen if you submit the paper without your advisor if they expected co-authorship.

Also, there is absolutely nothing awkward about this conversation, and you should learn to discuss authorship with your collaborators sooner rather than later.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, Yeah, I absolutely agree with you. I will bring this topic up in the most genuine way as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This varies by field and probably by place as well. In math it isn't usually the case that the advisor is a co-author unless they are a true collaborator. In some lab sciences (and elsewhere) it is common, even expected, that supervisors (PIs especially) will appear on nearly all work.

By rights, if not by custom, if you are the sole source of the intellectual ideas in the paper, then you should be the sole author. Author should mean that the person has an intellectual contribution. But in those lab sciences, that contribution might be there in fact, but somewhat remote.

For example, I don't appear as an author on any of my student's work (CS), though I gave them considerable guidance at times. But they were the intellectual drivers so get sole credit. Likewise, my doctoral advisor doesn't appear on my dissertation (math) or resulting paper, though he is the (attributed) creator of the proof of one of the key theorems (I had a different, less interesting, proof).

If you need to know, you need to ask directly. It isn't likely that this would be the first time the question has come up for them. And you need to learn the conventions of your field in any case.

Comment: Hi Buffy, thanks for your perspective, it really helps. I will ask them directly.

Answer (score -1):

If you send them a draft, say that you are about to submit this draft, and this draft does not have any authors listed, I would expect your supervisor to bring up the question of authorship themselves.

Comment: That is a pretty passive-aggressive way to 'deal' with it. Much better to be up front.

Comment: I don't think it's passive aggressive at all.